# Microphone Name Has Changed To USB PnP Sound Device

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, jack

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with 5.3.0-22.
I've been using this device for over a year, it's a Audio Technica AT2020-USB+ and until recently has always displayed as such.
I produce content for Youtube with OBS and use JACK with the microphone but keep Pulseaudio running for everything else.
On certain occasions with JACK becoming unresponsive the microphone would be unable to start with JACK, but would disappear from PAVUcontrol's configuration tab.
Usually a simple reboot would make all well, but this time upon reboot the microphone showed up as USB PnP Sound Device instead of it's proper name.
The microphone still works, but it's upsetting to not know why this has happened.

```
cat /proc/asound/cards      
 4 [Device]: USB-Audio - USB PnP Sound Device
            C-Media Electronics Inc. USB PnP Sound Device at usb-0000:07:00.0-1.4.1, full s
```

Another anomaly is alsamixer used to show Capture & Playback channels(It has a 1/8" headphone jack integrated)

Now it shows 4 channels: PCM, PCM Capture Source(No volume slider, toggles from Mic to Line), Line, and Mic Capture.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This is probably a hardware defect.

Comment: but the device is working fine and has always displayed the correct name in the past

Comment: The name is stored in an EEPROM chip. Apparently, that chip (or some solder connection between it and the USB chip) is broken. If no other customizations were done by AT, then this defect is harmless.